# Same custom post type with different ACF

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

In my WordPress site, there is a custom post-type called "Tournaments". Ten tournaments are same and one tournament is different than others. I want to add all the eleven tournaments under "Tournaments" post-type. Advanced Custom Fields are added to those 10 tournaments.

But how can I add different Advanced Custom Fields for one tournament which is under same custom post-type?

Thank you very much for any idea.

Comment: what about in Field Group - ACF conditions?

Comment: Thanks - @Lerry